# Why a pair of FieldRef must be specified for a Join?

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query

I'm writing a small js library to abstract away the annoyance and complexity of creating a CAML query.

In that regard, can you explain the significance of both `FieldRef` elements within a Join, when one must be necessarily implied by the other:

```
<Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='customer'>
   <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='CustomerName' RefType='Id'/>
     <FieldRef List='customer' Name='ID'/>
   </Eq>
</Join>
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx) clearly states (emphasis mine):

> The field in the primary list must be a Lookup type field and **it must lookup to the field in the foreign list**. For this reason, all joins mirror existing lookup relations between lists.

**Q:** Shouldn't just the field in the primary list suffice to deduce the second field? Or am I missing a use case?

===

For a broader context:

In the js library I'm trying to simplify the join query so it would look something like the following:

```
var query = SPHelper.query().from("Orders")
              .join({on: "CustomerName", as: "customer"})
              .select(["OrderId", "customer.Address as CustomerAddress"]);
```

to generate the above CAML Join query + `<ProjectedFields>` and `<ViewFields>`, and have as much information as possible deduced from metadata.

Comment: Are you aware of this project? https://camljs.codeplex.com/

Comment: @RobertKaucher, no. It's interesting - I'll take a look